# Detect re (regexp) object in Python

Tags: python, regex, types

I wonder what is the proper pythonic backward- and forward-compatible method how check if an object is compiled `re` object.

`isinstance` method cannot be easily used, while the resulting object claims to be `_sre.SRE_Pattern` object:

```
>>> import re
>>> rex = re.compile('')
>>> rex
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7f63db414390>
```

but there is no such one:

```
>>> import _sre
>>> _sre.SRE_Pattern
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SRE_Pattern'

>>> import sre
__main__:1: DeprecationWarning: The sre module is deprecated, please import re.
>>> sre.SRE_Pattern
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SRE_Pattern'

>>> re.SRE_Pattern
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SRE_Pattern'
```

I don't want to use duck typing (i.e. checking for the availability of some specific methods), because this could collide with some other types.

For now, I'm using:

```
>>> RegexpType = type(re.compile(''))
>>> type(rex) == RegexpType
True
```

but there might be a better way..

Comment: You should use `isinstance(rex, RegexpType)` in the last line to conform with [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  Apart from this, there doesn't seem to be a better way, except for trying to avoid such a test in the first place...

Comment: Sven, thanks, I was wrong that `isinstance` method could not be easily used :)

Comment: just to note `isinstance(rex, RegexpType)` is slower than `type(rex) == RegexpType` which is slower than `rex.__class__ == RegexpType`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type of compiled regex object in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102019/type-of-compiled-regex-object-in-python)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`re._pattern_type` exists, and appears to do what you want:

```
>>> isinstance(re.compile(''), re._pattern_type)
True
```

But this is not a good idea - per Python convention, names starting with _ are not part of the public API of a module and not part of the backward compatibility guarantees. So, using `type(re.compile(''))` is your best bet - though notice that this isn't guaranteed to work either, since the re module makes no mention of the object returned from re.compile() being of any particular class.

And indeed, even if this was guaranteed, the most Pythonic and back- and forward- compatible way would be to rely on the *interface*, rather than the type. In other words, embracing duck typing and EAFP, do something like this:

```
try:
     rex.match(my_string)
except AttributeError:
     # rex is not an re
else:
     # rex is an re
```

Comment: I can't agree with the advice to rely on the interface. Not in this case. Many objects can have a match attribute that might do completely different things. if `rex` could truly be anything, you have no idea what might happen when you call `rex.match`. This policy works when you know an object either has an attribute that does something expected or does not, but it doesn't work as well when it could have the attribute, not have the attribute, or have an attribute of the same name that might do something completely different.

Comment: Note that as of Python 3.7 `re._pattern_type` was replaced by `re.Pattern`.

Answer (score 3):

Following some of the recommendations you can come up with:

```
import re

# global constant
RE_TYPE = re.compile('').__class__

def is_regex(a):
    return isinstance(a, RE_TYPE)
```

Answer (score 1):

In [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102019/type-of-compiled-regex-object-in-python) there wasn't any answer other than solution you use, so I think there is no better way.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

print isinstance(<yourvar>, re.RE_Pattern)
```

Comment: in what Python implementation/version does re.RE_Pattern exist? I guess it does NOT in most ones, at least in x <= CPython <= 3.1.2, x < 2.6

Comment: Thank you for those who vote down and not leave comment - you are so cool))