# How do I test if an object is a regex pattern?

Tags: python, regex, types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Type of compiled regex object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102019/type-of-compiled-regex-object-in-python)

Usually I would do `isinstance(obj, ThePatternType)` but I cannot see how to get `ThePatternType`.

When I create an instance of a compiled regex pattern, the type gives:

```
type(pattern)
<type '_sre.SRE_Pattern'>
```

But for some reason I cannot do `from _sre import SRE_Pattern`

I realise I could do, `ThePatternType = type(re.compile(r'.'))`, but that just seems wrong!