# pexpect parse a string

Tags: python, string, parsing, pexpect

I have an expected string "Version 0.0.9999.0"

I do the spawn correctly then

```
e.expect('Version 0.0.9999.0')
```

and this works fine, however, I want to make it dynamic to accept any version (any 4 numbers separated by dots). Is this possible or does it have to be a specific string?
if yes, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are using actually expects a pattern and not a fixed string, as per [the documentation](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html#spawn-expect):

> expect(self, pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=None)
>
> This seeks through the stream until a pattern is matched. The
> pattern is overloaded and may take several types. The pattern can be a
> StringType, EOF, a compiled re, or a list of any of those types.
> Strings will be compiled to re types.

From what you say, the regular expression could be something like "Version \d.\d.\d{4}.\d", but it depends on the possible values for the version. For fixed strings there is expect_exact.

Comment: thanks. this works!
i have a small question: what are the "re types"? I checked the page u sent but the re types modules page crashes.

Comment: re types are [regular expression types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102019/type-of-compiled-regex-object-in-python). It may be useful to read [documentation on regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), in case you face more complex situations.