# When type([object]) is used in an if statement, why must it be typecasted into a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

When I execute the following code:

```
import re
phoneNumRegex = re.compile("")
print(type(phoneNumRegex))
```

I get output:

```
<class '_sre.SRE_Pattern'>
```

However, if I try and use `type(phoneNumRegex)` in an if statement, I need to typecast it into a `str` for it to work as intended:

```
if str(type(phoneNumRegex)) == "<class '_sre.SRE_Pattern'>":
    print("This if statement works")
```

Note how it reads `str(type(phoneNumRegex))` above, not `type(phoneNumRegex)`. My question is, why must I typecast `type(phoneNumRegex)` into a `str` when I use it in an if statement?

Comment: I think your confusing "parse" with "typecast" :)

Comment: @Signal you're right I've accepted your edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the [`type()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) returns a *type object*:

```
>>> type(type(phoneNumRegex)) 
<type 'type'>
```

A better way to check if a variable is of a certain type is using [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance). In case of a regular expression pattern type:

- [Type of compiled regex object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102019/type-of-compiled-regex-object-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Because `type()` does not return a String, it returns a `type`:

```
>>> a = 3
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(type(a))
<type 'type'>
```

When you `print` many types of objects, it will automatically call `__str__()` to get a string to print.  When using it in a conditional, you must do this manually.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing to a string, so of course you need a string to compare with.  Compare to a type instead:

```
>>> import re
>>> re_pattern_type = type(re.compile(''))
>>> re_pattern_type
<class '_sre.SRE_Pattern'>
>>> phone_regex = re.compile('\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}')
>>> phone_regex
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x0000000003F6FD50>
>>> if type(phone_regex) == re_pattern_type:
...     print('match')
... 
match
```

You can also check if you have an instance of a type:

```
>>> if isinstance(phone_regex,re_pattern_type):
...     print('yes')
...     
yes
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you can compare the type this way

```
import re
phoneNumRegex = re.compile("")
if phoneNumRegex.__class__  == re._pattern_type:
    print("This if statemnt works")
```