# How do I get a regex pattern type for MyPy

Tags: python, mypy

If I compile a regex

```
>>> type(re.compile(""))
<class '_sre.SRE_Pattern'>
```

And want to pass that regex to a function and use Mypy to type check

```
def my_func(compiled_regex: _sre.SRE_Pattern):
```

I'm running into this problem

```
>>> import _sre
>>> from _sre import SRE_Pattern
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'SRE_Pattern'
```

It seems that you can import `_sre` but for some reason `SRE_Pattern` isn't importable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type of compiled regex object in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102019/type-of-compiled-regex-object-in-python)

Comment: You can use `re._pattern_type` instead.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For Python>3.9, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66385107/) by Rotareti.

Historic answer follows.

---

`mypy` is very strict in terms of what it can accept, so you can't just generate the types or use import locations that it doesn't know how to support (otherwise it will just complain about library stubs for the syntax to a standard library import it doesn't understand).  Full solution:

```
import re
from typing import Pattern

def my_func(compiled_regex: Pattern):
    return compiled_regex.flags 

patt = re.compile('') 
print(my_func(patt))
```

Example run:

```
$ mypy foo.py 
$ python foo.py 
32
```

Comment: ignore this if you're on Python >=3.9

Answer (score 11):

Starting from **Python 3.9** `typing.Pattern` is [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Pattern).

> Deprecated since version 3.9: Classes Pattern and Match from re now support []. See PEP 585 and Generic Alias Type.

You should use the type `re.Pattern` instead:

```py
import re

def some_func(compiled_regex: re.Pattern):
    ...
```

Comment: Note that `re.Pattern` itself is generic at first and `mypy --strict` will complain: `error: Missing type parameters for generic type "Pattern"`. The `typing` docs say: *These types (and the corresponding functions) are generic in `AnyStr` and can be made specific by writing `Pattern[str]`, `Pattern[bytes]`, `Match[str]`, or `Match[bytes]`.*

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the types the `re` module uses aren't actually accessible by name. You'll need to use the [`typing.re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.re) types for type annotations instead:

```
import typing

def my_func(compiled_regex: typing.re.Pattern):
    ...
```

Comment: Note that `Pattern` has been moved to `typing`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Pattern

Comment: Mateen, it's the opposite. `typing.Pattern` has been deprecated in favor of `re.Pattern`.

Comment: @SiddharthaGandhi: It got changed twice. Mateen is talking about the first time it got changed. You're talking about a later change.