# What is the type of a compiled regular expression to be defined explicitly in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, types

I am writing a function to deal with pre-compiled regular expressions. How do I define this explicitly? E.g.

```
def use_regular_expression(regular_expression: ???):
    pass
```

What I am to write in place of "???" to only accept what `re.compile` outputs given a valid regular expression string?

`print(type(re.compile('')))` says `_sre.SRE_Pattern` and the PyCharm IDE suggests it's `re.__Regex` but neither seems to work no matter what of the obvious ways I try to import and specify them.

Comment: (the syntax `def my_function(arg : str):` doesn't accept only the specified type, you need to check this inside the function with i.e. `isinstance(obj, type)` or directly use a `try/except` statement and raise a TypeError)

Comment: @PRMoureu thank you, but this is the way I use to tell the IDE what type it is meant to be so it can provide relevant code completion hints and check the types on the fly at the code writing time. I also need to know the actual type to specify as the second argument of `isinstance` anyway.

Comment: print(type(re.compile("")))

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Printing the type says it's '_sre.SRE_Pattern', but if you pass that to isinstance, it says _sre is undefined. If you also import _sre, it says _sre has no attribute 'SRE_Pattern'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to whoever has marked my question to be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102019/type-of-compiled-regex-object-in-python) (I've failed to find it myself unfortunately) I have found the correct (i.e. exactly what I was looking for) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34178375/274627) written by [@flying-sheep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247482/flying-sheep), let me cite it here for those who may happen to stumble upon this instance of the question:

It's `typing.re.Pattern`.

E.g.

```
from typing.re import Pattern

my_re = re.compile('foo')
assert isinstance(my_re, Pattern)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have check source code of `re`. In its source code, there is one line to check the type of input.

```
if isinstance(pattern, _pattern_type): #line 294
```

And then I check what `_pattern_type` is.

```
_pattern_type = type(sre_compile.compile("", 0))  #It also gives "_sre.SRE_Pattern"
```

So as you can see, even in `re`'s source code, there is no way to explicitly point out the class of a compiled regex.

Unfortunately, your question seems unsolvable.

Further, using annotations in variable definition just tell IDE to check, but not really restrict in runtime. I recommend you to use:

```
assert type(regular_expression) == type(re.compile("", 0))
```

Comment: Thank you, but the question is not unsolvable actually, the answer is `typing.re.Pattern`.

Comment: @lvan Thank you too.